# Homebrew with Ansible, needs a "make install" kind of step

Tags: sudo, homebrew, ansible

Ansible attempts to install software on a box non-interactively. Ansible runs on a box with a "become" mode (where commands are as root) and a general-user mode.

Homebrew requires it be run not run as "root" user, meanwhile, parts of it do require "sudo," requiring a sudo password, preventing a tool like ansible from working with it.

Doing the Homebrew on the console, it feels like there's a basic piece of the work missing, analagous to "configure" based projects run in Linux. I'd happily go for a two step process: 1) "make" run as normal user, and "sudo make install" step run as superuser. Ansible could handle that cleanly, but it's not available with Homebrew.

Maybe I'm thinking this wrong. I'd love to hear ideas. Either I become super user or I don't, but the homebrew installer can't have it both ways to allow a non-interactive install through Ansible.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck, or what errors are you getting? And there seems to be an Ansible module for Homebrew… https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/homebrew_module.html

Comment: It appears the homebrew module is not designed to install brew, simply to install packages using brew that is already installed.